# csh (tcsh) ambiguous output redirect when assigning output of piped commands w/stderr redirect to variable in script

Tags: linux, shell, ping, csh

I'm trying to assign the output of my piped commands to a variable in a csh script.

The command is:

```
set VAR="`ping $1 2>&1 | grep 'unknown' | cut -b 7-13`"
```

This doesn't want to work, however.
I get a vague "Ambiguous output redirect."

I'm lost, because the command itself works when I type it in terminal, and I can see the text `unknown`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2>&1` isn't valid `csh` syntax. This only works for Bourne shells.

To pipe both stdout and stderr, you can use the `|&` operator.

Also note that `ping` will run forever by default, you probably want to add a `-c` option to limit the number of times it runs.

```
set VAR="`ping localhost -c 5 |& grep 'unknown' | cut -b 7-13`"
```

Comment: So my problem then is that the following commands that the output should be piped to do not work. I can change my command to `ping randomHost -c 5 | grep -o 'apple'`, and the output will still be the standard `ping: unknown host stuff`, presumably coming from stderr from the ping command.  But the actual commands I'm trying to run don't work, so there's no output to store in a variable

Comment: I thought I needed to redirect stderr to stdout so that those functions actually work, if the output to console is coming from stderr and piping only works on stdout.  That redirection fixed my problem in bash, at least.

Comment: @krb686 Right, you need stdout and stderr, this wasn't obvious :-) You can use `|&` for that.

Answer (score 2):

If that works interactively, your interactive shell is not csh... which is probably a good thing. Stderr redirection in csh uses just `>&` but only redirects stderr and stdout together into a file.

See also http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-9.html

If the intent is to figure out whether `$1` resolves, `ping` is the wrong tool anyway. Try

```
set VAR=`dig +short "$1" || echo unknown`
```

Comment: I completely forgot you are correct, I login with csh, but immediately run bash habitually now and forgot.  At this point, I am not sure which shell I can use for this script, so I'd still like to try and get this to work on csh, if possible. Also, if you have any information as to why it's a good thing my interactive shell is not csh, I'd like to know.  I've read a few sources, but am looking for more.

Comment: *" csh uses just >& but only redirects stderr to stdout."*: `>&` redirects stderr to a file, you can't redirect stderr to stdout in `csh`...

Comment: @carpetsmoker Huh? Maybe my wording is imprecise but what you are saying isn't correct either. `command >& file` redirects both stdout and stderr to the same file, so effectively redirects stderr to stdout, then stdout to the file. Sorry for sloppy explanation, and thanks for the comment; answer updated.

Comment: It seems I was mistaken, I thought `>&` only redirected stderr, and not stdout :-/

Comment: I am not familiar with `dig`, but it doesn't seem to be working the way I would expect. I can see it resolved `localhost` to an ip address with `dig +short localhost`, but it doesn't return anything when I try `dig +short otherhost`, with otherhost obviously the hostname.  Yet I can successfully ping otherhost.

Comment: Is `otherhost` declared in your `/etc/hosts`? Do you get better results with `host otherhost` or `nslookup otherhost`?

Comment: Then use one of them.  `dig` is nice because it can return results in machine-readable format, but if this is just for human consumption, any one of them should be fine.

Comment: For more information on why you should not use (t)csh for scripting: [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt)